# Persisting OneToMany with Embeddable Id in JPA

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

An authorisation service is based upon http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/ (sadly it doesn't provide a registration example)

I have the following Entities and Service:

**User.java**

```
package com.test.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1322120000551624359L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "activated")
  private Boolean activated;

  @Column(name = "activation_token")
  private String activationToken;

  @Column(name = "activation_token_exp")
  private Timestamp activationTokenExpirationDate;

  @Column(name = "reset_token")
  private String resetToken;

  @Column(name = "reset_token_exp")
  private Timestamp resetTokenExpirationDate;

  @Column(name = "created")
  private LocalDateTime created;

  @Column(name = "updated")
  private LocalDateTime updated;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private List<UserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>(0);

  public User() { }

  // getters and setters
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
  @Embeddable
  public static class Id implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1322120000551624359L;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    protected Long userId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    protected Role role;

    public Id() { }

    public Id(Long userId, Role role) {
      this.userId = userId;
      this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o)
        return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

      Id id = (Id) o;

      if (! userId.equals(id.userId))
        return false;
      return role == id.role;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int result = userId.hashCode();
      result = 31 * result + role.hashCode();
      return result;
    }
  }

  @EmbeddedId
  Id id = new Id();

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "role", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  protected Role role;

  public UserRole() {
  }

  public UserRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
  }

  public Role getRole() {
    return role;
  }

  public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
  }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Override
  public User registerUser(UserDTO userDto) {
    Optional<User> existingUser = this.getByUsername(userDto.getUsername());
    if (existingUser.isPresent()) {
      throw new RegistrationException("User is already taken");
    }

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
    newUser.setPassword(encoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    newUser.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
    newUser.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
    newUser.setActivated(Boolean.FALSE);
    newUser.setActivationToken(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
    newUser.setActivationTokenExpirationDate(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(ACTIVATION_TOKEN_TTL)));
    newUser.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());

    newUser.addRole(new UserRole(Role.MEMBER));

    return userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
```

This line  `return userRepository.save(newUser);` however throws an exception as is not able to persist the relation. I can't set the UserRole ID (userId + role) manually as I don't yet have them (the user is to be persisted)

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'role' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    ...
    ...
```

Is this the correct way to persist this kind of relation while having an composite primary key as Embeddable?

If I avoid setting the realation with UserRole, the user gets persisted correctly (with no roles)

**DB**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activation_token` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_token_exp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_token` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_token_exp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 5):

In `UserRole`, the role is mapped twice: once as a simple property

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "role", insertable = false, updatable = false)
protected Role role;
```

and once more inside the embedded id:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "role")
protected Role role;
```

At the time you call `userRepository.save(newUser)`, you've only set the simple property `UserRole.role` to point to a non-null role. However, since the simple property is marked as `insertable=false`, it is being ignored in the `INSERT` statement. `UserRole.id.role`, in turn, is set to `null` and that is the value that is being considered for the `INSERT` statement. Since you've created a non-null constraint for the `role` column, the `INSERT` statement fails.

(note that `DEFAULT ''` is only honored when the column is not present in the `INSERT` clause's field list, which is not the case here)

The solution is, simply, to update the value of `UserRole.id.role` whenever `User.role` is being set.

Answer (score 3):

Your `UserRole` class mapping is not correct. You have `Role` mapped twice once via the `EmbeddedId` and once directly in `UserRole`. You have to remove the second `UserRole`, the class will look like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1322120000551624359L;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        protected Long userId;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = "role")
        protected Role role;

        public Id() {
        }

        public Id(Long userId, Role role) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.role = role;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o)
                return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            Id id = (Id) o;

            if (!userId.equals(id.userId))
                return false;
            return role == id.role;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = userId.hashCode();
            result = 31 * result + role.hashCode();
            return result;
        }
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    Id id;

    public UserRole(Id id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Also, note `Id` is no longer initialised.Change the registerUser to  :

```
public User registerUser(String userName) {

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(userName);
    newUser.setPassword("password");
    newUser.setFirstName("name");
    //set other fields.

    userRepository.save(newUser);
    newUser.addRole(new UserRole(new UserRole.Id(newUser.getId(), Role.MEMBER)))
    userRepository.save(newUser);

    return newUser; 
}
```

When you are creating the composite primary key for `user_role` you provide only ROLE and not the user_id, JPA complains user_id as null. We need to provide both.