# How to properly insert an @Entity when there is an @Embeddable ID

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Here is my code

User class

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="APP_USER_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<UserRole> roles;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    protected User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password, List<UserRole> roles){
        this.username = username;
        this.email= email;
        this.password= password;
        this.roles= roles;
    }
```

UserRole Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {
    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1322120000551624359L;

        @Column(name = "APP_USER_ID")
        protected Integer userId;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = "ROLE")
        protected Role role;

        public Id() { }

        public Id(Integer userId, Role role) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.role = role;
        }
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    Id id = new Id();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ROLE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    protected Role role;

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
}
```

These are the tables in the database

- user Table -> 
  | id | email | password | username |
- user_role Table -> 
  | ROLE | APP_USER_ID |

In this project one user can have many roles.
In my service class i'm trying to save the user like this (The code below is not working,it is more like a pseudo code, but according to my current understanding i feel like i should follow this kind of an approach),

```
return userRepository.save(new User(username, email, encoder.encode(password)), 
            new List<UserRole>(){{
                add(//create a new UserRole...);
            }}));
```

I'm some what new to spring/hibernate and i cannot figure out how to insert a user properly to the database with hibernate.

Comment: "This is not working" What does this mean? Exception or no exception but no data in tables as well? Share the exception stacktrace if you have one.

Comment: @Rohit i edited the question. My code is a not working. I need to know how to properly insert an user to the database.

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769044/persisting-onetomany-with-embeddable-id-in-jpa/44872119#44872119) not help you?

Comment: @Rohit no. Because what is the value should i pass as the USERID ? How do i get the id of the user that i'm inserting at the same time?

Comment: How is your Id in User genertaed?

Comment: @Rohit it is auto generated. See the user class code "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)"

Comment: Then I dont think you can generate User and UserRole together, like my answer says in that link.

Answer (score 0):

The `UserRole` class doesn't have any constructor that takes any arguments so you can't write this: `new UserRole(USERID,"ADMIN")`, however you want to create a `userId` by the inner class `Id` so probably you need to write it like this: `new UserRole.Id(USERID,"ADMIN")`.

Comment: How do i get the USERID ?